# How to extract children in outlet

Tags: angular

I access to a page of my app with :

myApp.com/#/accident/(carsContainer:robustness)

In the accident component I would like to extract the "robustness" part. I suppose I must use the ActivatedRoute but cannot find a way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `accident` component you can subscribe to router event and get the url and then extract whatever you need from it. Something like this:

```
import { Router, NavigationEnd, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router){}

ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events
        .filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
        .map(() => this.activatedRoute)
        .map((route) => {
            while (route.firstChild) route = route.firstChild;
            console.log(route.snapshot.url[0].path)
            return route;
        })
        .subscribe((event) => {
            console.log('NavigationEnd:', event);
        });
}
```